# Channel closed after first write

Tags: java, tcp, netty

I wrote a client class that handles multiple TCP connections to different TCP servers as follows:

```
    private int nThreads;
    private Charset charset;
    private Bootstrap bootstrap;

    private Map<String, Channel> channels = new HashMap<String, Channel>();

    public MyClass() {
        bootstrap = new Bootstrap()
            .group(new NioEventLoopGroup(nThreads))
            .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
            .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
            .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new StringEncoder(charset));
                }
            });
    }

    public void send(MyObject myObject) {
        final String socket = myobject.getSocket();

        //Check if a channel already exists for this socket
        Channel channel = channels.get(socket);
        if(channel == null) {
            /* No channel found for this socket. */

            //Extract host and port from socket
            String[] hostport = socket.split(":", 2);
            int port = Integer.parseInt(hostport[1]);

            //Create new channel
            ChannelFuture connectionFuture;
            try {
                connectionFuture = bootstrap.connect(hostport[0], port).await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }

            //Connection operation is completed, check status
            if(!connectionFuture.isSuccess()) {
                return;
            }

            //Add channel to the map
            channel = connectionFuture.channel();
            channels.put(notifSocket, channel);
        }

        //Write message on channel
        final String message = myObject.getMessage();
        channel.writeAndFlush(message).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
            @Override
            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
                if(!future.isSuccess()) {
                    //Log cause
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

When the `send()` method is called for the first time for a given socket, a connection is established to the remote server and the message is correctly sent. However, when the `send()` method is called a second time for the same socket, the `Channel` is found in the map but the `writeAndFlush()` operation fails and the cause indicates the channel is closed.

I don't see anywhere in my code where I close this `Channel`. Is there a special configuration to avoid Netty closing the `Channel`?

Thanks,
Mickael

Answer (score -1):

The remote-host may closed the channel as it idled to long. You will need to implement some kind of heartbeat to make sure the channel stays active.

Comment: The *channel* is closed. You're talking about the *connection.*